# ESP32 and Flask Server Communication

Tags: flask, iot, esp32

I am trying to make our thesis project which involves an exchange of commands from flask server to esp32 and vice versa. Basically, I need the ttp223-b data from esp32 and use it in my flask server, and in exchange my flask server would control the leds and lcd 16x2 on my esp32. can anyone help me with this please?

Still haven't tried anything. been confused of all the stuff on yt

Comment: Do it piece by piece. You should be able to find examples of how to do all these things. You need to decide what "use it in my flask server" actually means. Get each piece working, then combine them. When you run into problems ask specific detailed questions about the problems. Otherwise as it is you're asking someone to do your thesis project for you.

Comment: hi, I already fixed the problem but thankyou for your response. <3